# Makefile specify different compilation flags based on two groups of objects

Tags: makefile

In my makefile I compile files like shown below:

```
a_SRCS = $(shell find $(DIR1) -name '*.c') 
b_SRCS = $(shell find $(DIR2) -name '*.c')

a_OBJS = $(patsubst $(SRC)/%.c,$(OBJ)/%.o,$(a_SRCS))
b_OBJS = $(patsubst $(SRC)/%.c,$(OBJ)/%.o,$(b_SRCS))

$(BIN): $(a_OBJS) $(b_OBJS)
$(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS) 

$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
$(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

I would like to specify different compilation flags based on if the current object to be generated `$(OBJ)/%.o` belongs to `$a_OBJS` or `$b_OBJS`. Something like below. Is it possible to do?

```
#for a_OBJS
$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
$(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(a_CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 

#for b_OBJS
$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
$(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(b_CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: If we are talking gnu make, it has peer target variables https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html):

```
$(a_OBJS) : EXTRA_FLAGS = -DA_OBJ

$(b_OBJS) : EXTRA_FLAGS = -DB_OBJ

$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
        $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(EXTRA_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Oh man, you have no idea how much time I've spend trying to implement this before asking the question. And it turns out so simple... Many thanks!